# Failed to connect Java program in Windows Eclipse to Kafka in Ubuntu from the same machine, same network?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, wsl-2

I read this [post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/) and I am doing the following in my own single local machine. I am using a Windows machine and just installed Ubuntu. I installed Java 8 on Ubuntu and can run Kafka smoothly. By that, I mean I can open two separate terminals of consumer and producer and they can talk to each other successfully.

I have also written a Java program in Eclipse and Eclipse points to a **different** JRE.

However, when I run my Java program in Eclipse to produce / consume messages in Kafka, nothing is printed to Ubuntu's consumer. My Java does not connect to Kafka at all.

What have I done wrong here?

I notice that when I start the ZooKeeper and Kafka in CMD, I am able to connect my Java Program to Kafka.  However, when I start the ZooKeeper and Kafka in Ubuntu, my Java program can never connect to Kafka server there.

Commands to start ZooKeeper, Kafka and consumer in Ubuntu:

```
# start zookeeper
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
# start kafka 
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
# create TestTopics
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic TestTopic
# start consumer
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic TestTopic -from-beginning
```

**Java Program in Eclipse**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

public class ProducerTesting {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         *  Producer
         * 
         * */
        // properties for producer
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092");
        props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        
        // create producer
        Producer<Integer, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<Integer,String>(props);
        
        // send messages to my topics
        for(int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
            ProducerRecord<Integer,String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<Integer,String>("TestTopic",i,"testing" + LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Hong_Kong"))));
            producer.send(producerRecord);
        }
        
        // close producer
        producer.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have two physical separate machines - a windows and a ubuntu one? Outside of eclipse (at the windows command prompt) prove you have connectivity to the Kafka running on the ubuntu box. Start showing you can ping it (resolve the name, etc) and then use CURL or something to check you can hit the Kafka application itself. Your java code also seems to define ``localhost:9092`` as the ``bootstrap.servers`` value. But the kafka on 9092 is on the ubuntu server, not localhost?

Comment: hi @JohnXF thanks for your comments. I didn't really know the ubuntu I installed in Windows is being seens as a separate machine here. In this case, can they be sharing the same IP address ? And I am just very lost here. Can you elaborate on how I can ping it ?

Comment: How do you mean the 'ubuntu installed in windows'??? Are you talking about a virtual machine or something?

Comment: I mean i followed this link to install Ubuntu in Window. Sorry for the confusion. https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Comment: Yes, that is quite important information. So the problem sounds like the WSL is not exposing the port to the host (windows machine). You should do some research on that. eg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking and https://dev.to/vishnumohanrk/wsl-port-forwarding-2e22

Comment: By default, Kafka doesn't expose itself outside of the WSL2 hypervisor machine. Plus, you need a port forward

Comment: Along with the above Microsoft docs, you'll want to read this (pretend WSL2 is like Docker) https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Thanks all for the generous ideas. I have to say they are a bit technical for me. My understanding is that the Linus server IP address first and then port forward and then also create a kafka listener. Perhaps I should just get confluent kafka and there won't be issue like these.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Confluent Kafka" It's all the same *Apache* Kafka. If you mean pay for Confluent Cloud, then, yes, that's an alternative that'll require payment.

Comment: thanks for the heads-up. You have been very helpful and knowledgable. Will read the links you recommended above once again to get around the issue then,